# Using Epsilon Delta to prove that for a continuous odd function, f(0)=0

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose f(x) is a continuous odd function defined on [−∞,∞].

Prove that f(0) = 0.

I believe the answer requires using the definition of continuity/limits in order to prove that for an odd function, f(0)=0

Comment: I mean, you don't need continuity for this. Just recognize that $f(-0) = -f(0) = f(0)$. This implies that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats +1 though I would tweak your  order so $f(0)=f(-0)=-f(0)$ with the first equality being due to $0=-0$ and the second because you have an odd function

Comment: Ye nice, that is much better

Answer (score 1):

1.) f is odd $\Rightarrow f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

2.) f is continous in $\mathbb{R}$, this implies that f is continous in zero. Therefore
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x) =f(0)$$

Now, the first lateral limit can be rewritten
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(-x)$$

and f is odd, so
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(-x)=-\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)$$

By continuity
$$
\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} 
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=-f(0) \\
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=f(0) \\
\end{array}\right\rbrace.
\Rightarrow f(0)=-f(0)
$$

And the only solution for $f(0)=-f(0)$ is $f(0)=0$.

Comment: It has already been pointed put in the comments that continuity of $f$ is unnecessary.

Comment: I think that continuity is required for cases where f is not defined at 0, for example $f(x)= \left\lbrace \begin{array}{lcr} 1 & \text{if} & x>0 \\ -1 & \text{if} & x<0 \\ \end{array}\right. $

Comment: If $f$ is not defined at $0$ how can you write $f(0)=0$?